# Cosmos DB query using SQL works when running in Data explorer but not when executed with the C# DocumentClient

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a query that is meant to count up the number of fresh and stale documents of a particular type.

Given the fact that I try to get the count for more than one type in one query there is a good chance that the query should be rewritten and that the new version works as expected when using C#.

The query works if I run in it the Cosmos DB Data Explorer using the "New SQL Query", but when running the same query using the `2.2.2` and `2.8.1` (upgraded to latest version) versions of the DocumentClient in the `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` nuget package it does not.

Given the following documents:

### Data

```
[{
    "PartitionKey": "partition",
    "SomeKey": "foo",
    "Type": "DocumentType",
    "Value": "1",
    "StaleAfterThis": 101
},
{
    "PartitionKey": "partition",
    "SomeKey": "bar",
    "Type": "DocumentType",
    "Value": "2",
    "StaleAfterThis": 90
},
{
    "PartitionKey": "partition",
    "SomeKey": "bar",
    "Type": "DocumentType",
    "Value": "3",
    "StaleAfterThis": 500
},
{
    "PartitionKey": "partition",
    "SomeKey": "foo",
    "Type": "DocumentType",
    "Value": "4",
    "StaleAfterThis": 500
}]
```

And the following query:

### Query

```sql
SELECT
    SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = 'foo' AND c.PartitionKey = 'partition' AND c.StaleAfterThis < 100)) as StaleFooCount,
    SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = 'foo' AND c.PartitionKey = 'partition' AND c.StaleAfterThis >= 100)) as FreshFooCount,
    SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = 'bar' AND c.PartitionKey = 'partition' AND c.StaleAfterThis < 100)) as StaleBarCount,
    SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = 'bar' AND c.PartitionKey = 'partition' AND c.StaleAfterThis >= 100)) as FreshBarCount
FROM c
WHERE
    c.Type = 'DocumentType' AND
    c.PartitionKey = 'partition'
```

When running this query in the web based query editor in Data Explorer the result is as expected.

```
[
    {
        "StaleFooCount": 0,
        "FreshFooCount": 1,
        "StaleBarCount": 1,
        "FreshBarCount": 1
    }
]
```

If I try the same query using C# the DocumentClient all of the values are 0. This is the case both when returning a dynamic result and a typed one.

### C# typed query example

```cs
var queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 };

var queryText =
    @"SELECT
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = '@foo' AND c.PartitionKey = '@partitionKey' AND c.StaleAfterThis < @staleAfterThis)) as StaleFooCount,
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = '@foo' AND c.PartitionKey = '@partitionKey' AND c.StaleAfterThis >= @staleAfterThis)) as FreshFooCount,
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = '@bar' AND c.PartitionKey = '@partitionKey' AND c.StaleAfterThis < @staleAfterThis)) as StaleBarCount,
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey = '@bar' AND c.PartitionKey = '@partitionKey' AND c.StaleAfterThis >= @staleAfterThis)) as FreshBarCount
    FROM c
    WHERE
        c.Type = 'DocumentType' AND
        c.PartitionKey = '@partitionKey'";

var queryParameters = new SqlParameterCollection
{
    new SqlParameter("@partitionKey", "partition"),
    new SqlParameter("@foo", FooBarEnum.Foo.ToString()),
    new SqlParameter("@bar", FooBarEnum.Bar.ToString()),
    new SqlParameter("@staleAfterThis", 100)
};

var sqlQuerySpec = new SqlQuerySpec(queryText, queryParameters);

var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<TempResult>(_collectionLink, sqlQuerySpec, queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

var totalStaleDocuments = new TempResult();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    foreach (var result in await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TempResult>())
    {
        totalStaleDocuments.FreshFooCount += result.FreshFooCount;
        totalStaleDocuments.StaleFooCount += result.StaleFooCount;
        totalStaleDocuments.FreshBarCount += result.FreshBarCount;
        totalStaleDocuments.StaleBarCount += result.StaleBarCount;
    }
}

public class TempResult
{
    public int StaleFooCount { get; set; }
    public int FreshFooCount { get; set; }
    public int StaleBarCount { get; set; }
    public int FreshBarCount { get; set; }
}
```

### Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "StaleFooCount": 0,
        "FreshFooCount": 1,
        "StaleBarCount": 1,
        "FreshBarCount": 1
    }
]
```

### Result when executing query using C#:

```
[
    {
        "StaleFooCount": 0,
        "FreshFooCount": 0,
        "StaleBarCount": 0,
        "FreshBarCount": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# query is not the same. In your Portal query you are doing `c.SomeKey = 'foo'` while in C# you are doing `c.Type = '@foo'`

And finally, remove the `'` from the query parameters, like so:

```
 var queryText =
            @"SELECT
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey  = @foo AND c.PartitionKey = @partitionKey AND c.StaleAfterThis < @staleAfterThis)) as StaleFooCount,
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey  = @foo AND c.PartitionKey = @partitionKey AND c.StaleAfterThis >= @staleAfterThis)) as FreshFooCount,
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey  = @bar AND c.PartitionKey = @partitionKey AND c.StaleAfterThis < @staleAfterThis)) as StaleBarCount,
        SUM((SELECT VALUE Count(1) WHERE c.SomeKey  = @bar AND c.PartitionKey = @partitionKey AND c.StaleAfterThis >= @staleAfterThis)) as FreshBarCount
    FROM c
    WHERE
        c.Type = 'DocumentType' AND
        c.PartitionKey = @partitionKey";
```

Comment: Removing the ' from the query parameters was the reason for it not working. Thanks!

The c.SomeKey and c.Type was a mixup when trying to create an anonymized version of the query. I'll update the question to reflect that.